# rails migration unique key on 3 columns in rails (sql server)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sql-server, migration

I have this table on my Database:

```
create_table :month_holidays_translations, :id => false do |t|
  t.integer :month_holidays_id, null: false
  t.string :month, null: false
  t.string :language, null: false
end
```

I want to create a migration that creates a multiple unique key on columns: month_holidays_id, month and language. How I do that?
When I do add_index (code below) this create a index but not a unique key in my sql server database.

```
add_index "month_holidays_translations", ["month_holidays_id", "month", "language"], :unique => true
```

Comment: i believe unique constraint comes with the unique index. so this should work. `add_index :month_holidays_translations, [:month_holidays_id, :month, :language], :unique => true`

Comment: What do you mean by unique key? The `unique: true` options makes sure that your indices are unique, what else do you expect to see as a result?

Comment: I don't want this:

` #<MonthHolidaysTranslation:0x007fe966137550 month_holidays_id: 1, month: "February", language: "EN">,
 #<MonthHolidaysTranslation:0x007fe9781370f0 month_holidays_id: 1, month: "February", language: "EN">`

Comment: @lolix for constraints. see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

if you want adding a constraint without an index. This will depend on what database you're using. But below will work in your case.

```
class AddUniqeConstraintToMonthHolidaysTranslations < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def up
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE month_holidays_translations ADD constraint month_holidays_id_month_language UNIQUE (month_holidays_id, month, language);
    SQL
  end
  def down
    execute <<-SQL
      ALTER TABLE month_holidays_translations
        drop constraint if exists month_holidays_id_month_language;
    SQL
  end
end
```

you can check the reference for further details [SQL UNIQUE Constraint](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)